# Is allowing the user to add any code in TWIG a security hole?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my application, I want to allow the user to add his own Twig code. But, I don't want it to execute any back-end code (like PHP code to get access to database or files). I have tested using php code `<?php print "hello"; ?>`. I can see the PHP code does not execute on the Twig page.

To my knowledge, I can say there is no way to execute PHP code (that can manipulate files or database) in a Twig file unless calling an extension.

But, I just want to know more advises.

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question without seeing your code. As with most languages, executing user input can be risky if not correctly handled. We would need to know what you're doing to make this safe before being able to give you a useful answer.

Comment: Why would you want  this? Just let your end user use a wysiwyg like `CKEditor`

Comment: As @DarkBee wrote it. My application is like a wysiwyg. I let the user write his own Twig code and create automatically a twig file that runs on my server. Unfortunately I cannot show any code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could take a look at the **sandbox extension** of twig. You can set up a policy and explicitly define each single tag, filter, method, property and function. This was an advice I got after passing my application through a security-penetration-test. You can set it up globally or inside your controller which renders the user twig-input.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/sandbox.html

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#sandbox-extension

```
/**
 * Adds sandbox limitations to twig-environment to prevent template-injections
 *
 * @return \Twig_Environment
 */
private function getSandboxedTwigEnvironment()
{
    $tags = array('if', 'include', 'import', 'block', 'set', 'for');
    $filters = array('date', 'escape', 'trans', 'split', 'length', 'slice', 'lower', 'raw');
    $methods = array();
    $properties = array();
    $functions = array('include', 'path', 'absolute_url', 'asset', 'is_granted');

    $policy = new Twig_Sandbox_SecurityPolicy($tags, $filters, $methods, $properties, $functions);
    $sandbox = new Twig_Extension_Sandbox($policy);

    $twigEnvironment = $this->getCentralService()->getTwigEnvironment();
    $twigEnvironment->addExtension($sandbox);

    return $twigEnvironment;
}
```

An exception of **Twig_Sandbox_SecurityError** will be thrown if any forbidden tags, filter etc were added to the user-input.

Comment: Thanks. What could happen if I do not use a `Twig_Sandbox_SecurityPolicy`? Can you show a security hole example on a twig file that I can test?

Comment: In my application there is a textarea combined with the js-library "ace-editor" for a convenient way to add new email-templates with twig-syntax. The testers added the following code: {{ source('/etc/passwd') }} and where able to display sensitive server-information inside the application. Now it´s not possible anymore thanks to the sandbox-extension and the defined policy.

Comment: Cool. I see now.

Answer (score 0):

Just be careful if any of your context parameters (the params you use to render a template) are objects which implement the [ArrayAccess](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface - these can in some circumstances bypass the property/method policies in your sandbox because Twig treats them like arrays. E.g., try passing an Eloquent Model, and you'll notice you can easily access properties and relations (and perhaps even be able to execute query methods!) despite having a 100% strict security policy.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out a blackhat talk - https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-15/materials/us-15-Kettle-Server-Side-Template-Injection-RCE-For-The-Modern-Web-App-wp.pdf

It is possible to execute code on server using that, but they will still need to bypass the sandbox.